# Why does my scroll-top method only work after the first time executing?

Tags: jquery, methods, vuejs2

I have a Vue.js component App.vue and I want to dynamically attach/detach components with @click combined with v-if, v-else directive. I also want the jQuery animate scroll. This is my code :

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <RingsProduction v-if="flag"></RingsProduction>
        <RingsGuide v-else></RingsGuide>
        <nav @click="scroll" aria-label="Page navigation" class="text-center js-btn">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li>
                    <a aria-label="Previous">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a aria-label="Next">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import RingsProduction from "./components/RingsProduction.vue";
    import RingsGuide from "./components/RingsGuide.vue";

    export default {
        name: "app",
        components: {
            RingsProduction,
            RingsGuide
        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                flag: true
            };
        },
        methods: {
            scroll: function () {
                $(".js-btn").click(function () {
                    $("html, body").animate(
                        {
                            scrollTop: $(".scroll-top").offset().top
                        },
                        200
                    );
                });
                this.flag = !this.flag;
            }
        }
    };
</script>

<style lang="sass">
    .pagination cursor: pointer
</style>
```

Everything works fine but after 1st click. When I first click on navigation bar the flag is changing, but scroll did not run. The components changed, but scroll is still on bottom of the page. After 2nd click it works like it should. I don't get any console or Vue dev warnings or errors so I stucked without ideas.

The most strange thing is that actually works perfectly after 1st click.

Comment: If you're needing JQuery with Vue, you're missing the point of Vue IMO. Sure there are some instances where it might be good (some libraries, graphs etc) but in this instance it's a waste.

Comment: It is not that I needed it but it is way simpler to use jQuery method animate to scroll to the top of the site, that write a code in vanilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong but you are already listening to "click" event with @click binding. What I think is happening here is when you call scroll function @click you are setting an event listener:
`$(".js-btn").click(function () {` 
And then once you click the second time this event listener is running the code.
How about removing this part?

```
$(".js-btn").click(function () {
```

Your code can look like this:

```
<script>
    import RingsProduction from "./components/RingsProduction.vue";
    import RingsGuide from "./components/RingsGuide.vue";

    export default {
        name: "app",
        components: {
            RingsProduction,
            RingsGuide
        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                flag: true
            };
        },
        methods: {
            scroll: function () {

                    $("html, body").animate(
                        {
                            scrollTop: $(".scroll-top").offset().top
                        },
                        200
                    );

                this.flag = !this.flag;
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be If you can try switching to .on method to register the event handler 'click' for the button